# print a returned string in java

Tags: java, string, methods

I am trying to print the returned string value in the main method but I can't figure it out. can someone give me a hand?

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Main {


public static void main(String[] args) {


    String in_word;
    int number_input;

    Scanner input_word = new Scanner (System.in);
    Scanner input_times = new Scanner (System.in);


    System.out.println("Enter word: ");
    in_word = input_word.next();
    System.out.println("Enter number of times to concatenate: ");
    number_input = input_times.nextInt();



    multiConcat(in_word, number_input);

}
public static String multiConcat(String word, int times) {
    //String word;
    String s = "";
    int number;//times, ;


    for (number = 0; number < times; number++)
        s = word.concat(s);

    return s;

}


}
```

Comment: You need to print the returned String. Put your method call inside System.out.println ().

Answer (score 2):

```
System.out.println(multiConcat(in_word, number_input));
```